# The template function 'reference' is not expected when feeding API Management private IP addresses into private DNS entry with Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-api-management, azure-bicep

I want to create DNS A records for my internal API Management instance in a private DNS zone `azure-api.net` along with the API Management deployment:

```
var privateDnsZoneName = 'azure-api.net'
resource privateDnsZone 'Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones@2020-06-01' = {
  name: privateDnsZoneName
  location: 'Global'
}

resource privateDnsZoneEntry 'Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/A@2020-06-01' = {
  name: apim.name
  parent: privateDnsZone
  properties: {
    aRecords: [for addr in apim.properties.privateIPAddresses: {
      ipv4Address: addr
    }]
    ttl: 3600
  }
}
```

However when deploying it results into this error:

```
Line |
  57 |  New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | 17:12:13 - Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource
     | '[format('{0}/{1}', variables('privateDnsZoneName'), parameters('apimName'))]' at line '221' and column '9' is not
     | valid: The template function 'reference' is not expected at this location. Please see
     | https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for
     | usage details.'.
```

It seems that `reference()` function is not supported at this place (in ARM):

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/A",
  "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
  "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', variables('privateDnsZoneName'), parameters('apimName'))]",
  "properties": {
    "copy": [
      {
        "name": "aRecords",
        "count": "[length(reference(resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service', parameters('apimName'))).privateIPAddresses)]",
        "input": {
          "ipv4Address": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service', parameters('apimName'))).privateIPAddresses[copyIndex('aRecords')]]"
        }
      }
    ],
    "ttl": 3600
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service', parameters('apimName'))]",
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones', variables('privateDnsZoneName'))]"
  ]
}
```

Trying with a variable in between results in the same error - as practically the same ARM JSON is generated.

```
var privateDnsZoneName = 'azure-api.net'
resource privateDnsZone 'Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones@2020-06-01' = {
  name: privateDnsZoneName
  location: 'Global'
}

var apimPrivateIPAddresses = apim.properties.privateIPAddresses

resource privateDnsZoneEntry 'Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/A@2020-06-01' = {
  name: apim.name
  parent: privateDnsZone
  properties: {
    aRecords: [for addr in apimPrivateIPAddresses: {
      ipv4Address: addr
    }]
    ttl: 3600
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found no other way than to split private DNS zone + record creation into a **Bicep** module and with that getting rid of the `reference()` function:

```
param privateDnsZoneName string = 'azure-api.net'
param privateDnsARecordName string
param privateDnsARecordAddresses array

resource privateDnsZone 'Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones@2020-06-01' = {
  name: privateDnsZoneName
  location: 'Global'
}

resource privateDnsZoneEntry 'Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/A@2020-06-01' = {
  name: privateDnsARecordName
  parent: privateDnsZone
  properties: {
    aRecords: [for addr in privateDnsARecordAddresses: {
      ipv4Address: addr
    }]
    ttl: 3600
  }
}
```

and passing the `privateIPAddresses` array to the module.

```
module privateDnsEntry './private-dns.bicep' = {
  name: 'apim-private-dns'
  params: {
    privateDnsZoneName: 'azure-api.net'
    privateDnsARecordName: apim.name
    privateDnsARecordAddresses: apim.properties.privateIPAddresses
  }
}
```

Comment: you're right, arrays to iterate over in runtime need to be deployment-time constants, so they can be either varaibles or parameters. would you be so kind and sumbit an issue in bicep github saying that compiler didn't catch that case?

Comment: @Miq - done https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/2394